# Android In App Purchase Problems

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I've implemented In App purchase in my account using static response id `android.test.purchased`. Now when purchase the item a `Toast` popups saying **"Thank you. Your item will appear shortly."**

I think so far every thing works perfectly.

My problem is

Where does this `Toast` comes from. I couldn't find out it my code.

How can I override this Toast? Is it because of the `Reserved product ID` I used? Will it change once I use my own product Ids?

Which overridden function should be used know whether User has purchased or cancelled the request.

```
    @Override
    public void onPurchaseStateChange(PurchaseState purchaseState, String itemId,
            long purchaseTime, String developerPayload) {       
        if (purchaseState == PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {             
            // Is it here?
        }
    }
```

And finally, can I perform User Interface modifications within `onPurchaseStateChange`?

Here's my `onPurchaseStateChange` methode

```
    @Override
    public void onPurchaseStateChange(PurchaseState purchaseState, String itemId,
            long purchaseTime, String developerPayload) {
        if (Consts.DEBUG) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPurchaseStateChange() itemId: " + itemId + " " + purchaseState);
        }            
        if (purchaseState == PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
            for (CatalogEntry e : CATALOG) {
                if (e.sku.equals(itemId) &&
                        e.managed.equals(Managed.SUBSCRIPTION)) {
                }
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "purchase failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :) Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399963/android-in-app-billing-remove-default-toast-message

Comment: That link is returning a 404 now. Does anyone know how to remove the toast message? or can point to the correct link.

Comment: refer this link, it might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197295/how-to-change-toast-message-that-comes-after-successfull-purchase-of-a-product-i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly the toast comes from the market place activity. The link that user1378730 posted in the comments explains about how it gets removed.

Determining the outcome of the purchase in `onPurchaseStateChange` as you have done is correct, the purchaseState object has several enumerations that you will be able to check.

I would not suggest performing interface interactions in the `onPurchaseStateChange` method, as it may be called several times whilst the purchase is being completed. I jump out of that method to some custom ones on my activity to decide what to do e.g. a `onPurchaseCancel` and `onPurchaseSuccess` method that can tell if it's already run it's self. Doing this also allows you to separate the market interactions from the rest of your code flow, makes for easier debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the response. First portion is clear now.Secondly Now Im using reserved purchase id `android.test.purchase` for testing. Ive put a toast message in `onPurchaseStateChange` method. But its not shown. Is it because of the reserved id I used?

Comment: You should still see your own Toasts. What context have you run the toast under, is it the context of the activity or of some custom class? Also make sure you have the .show method on the toast!

Comment: No bro, Im not getting the toast that ive added in my code. Ive added the `onPurchaseStateChange` in to the question. You can go through that.

Comment: I'm still getting the same toast, and my app is live as well as the IAP product.

Comment: I also wanted to suppress the standard Toast so that I could show my own with more appropriate wording, but I wasn't able to. I do show my own toast, but it doesn't appear until the standard toast's appears and expires.

Are you showing your Toast from the UI thread? You should be.