# Remove "Thank you. Your item will appear shortly." toast from appearing after InApp Purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, toast

After I make a IAP purchase a Toast pops up (Thank you. Your item will appear shortly). Seem as if though this is coming from the Google's Market/Play client since I certainly don't have any code that does it.

Question: How do I remove this? Is it possible?

Comment: I haven't figured out how to suppress this Toast. Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896735/android-in-app-purchase-problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The toast is coming from the Google Play app, and you can't suppress it as it is not part of your application.

It is like any other toast from a third party app, completely outside your control.