# How to change toast message that comes after successful purchase of a product in in-app billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am getting a message like "Thank You,Your item will be appear shortly" after user purchase the product.Now this message comes from the market place side.But i want a custom message instead of this one.

How to do the same or at least how can I remove this toast notification?

Comment: you cant do that. there isn't any direct/indirect way to deal with it.

Comment: but there should be some way of dealing with external or market side notifications.I want this as the message said your item will appear shortly however it is already available to user.hence creates confusion.

Comment: What IAP library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

> As other users have said, you **cannot** change the toast from the Play
>   Store.

You will have to edit the Play Store App for that.

> What you ***CAN*** do is to check if the purchase succeeded and show
>   your own toast saying "The item is available now"

This message will work well with the toast that the Play Store shows.